# Length of public key vs encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, x509

I'm trying to understand the mechanism of encryption used on the web.
One thing is not clear to me at this point:
If I check, for example, google.com certificate, I can see that the public key is 4320 bits long, but Chrome shows that the connection is encrypted using AES_128_GCM, that I would expect to work with 128 bit keys.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4320 bits in the public key algorithm are used to encrypt the 128 bits in the symmetric key algorithm. The public key establishes a secure channel of communication between two parties who initially don't have any shared key. Think of this as a low bandwidth channel, which isn't very useful due to the computationally expensive nature of the public key algorithm. In practice -- the sole use of this public-key is to communicate a shared key to establish a high bandwidth channel which uses something like AES (which requires both parties to have the same key). The overall process is an example of a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, just to double check that I got it right, indeed, the public key is the one in the certificate (it is not hashed nor encrypted), but the actual data encryption is done using symetric keys encryption (making use of public/private keys encryption only to assure the symmetric key transfer in secure conditions)

Comment: Yes. The first public key system was the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange which transmitted no information whatsoever but allowed two parties to securely agree upon a common key. Later systems (e.g. RSA, ElGamal) allow for actual data to be transmitted, but in practice they are used much as Diffie-Hellman --  just to establish a shared key.

Answer (score 1):

The whole process is more involved but here are the basis to answer the question.

The data is encrypted with a symmetric algorythm such as AES, it is fast, secure and can handle any length of data.

The symmetric key is encrypted by an asymetric algorythm sucb as RSA or EC, they are slow and the data length is limited by the key length.

There are many articles on the Internet about HTTPS, it can get quite complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the exact answer, unfortunately I can't choose two "accepted" answers, even though both you posted almost in the same time.

Comment: NP, @John has a more copmplete answer.